# JQuery plugin isn't called more than once on my page

Tags: jquery, plugins

I have a JQuery plugin that blanks a textbox when the focus is on it and repaints the textbox with the text set on the value of the parameter.
I would like it to be called for each textbox I specify on my page but it only gets called for the last one I specified.

The Plugin code goes as follows:

```
(function( $ ){

    $.fn.foco = function(value){

        if ( $(this).length ) {

                var text = {
                    texto:null
                    };
                enfocar = $.extend(text  , value);      

                $(this).val(enfocar.texto);

                $(this).focus(function(){
                    if($(this).val() == enfocar.texto)
                          $(this).val('');                      
                }).blur(function(){
                    if($(this).val() == '')
                        $(this).val(enfocar.texto);                     
                });             


        } else {

                return false;

        }

    }

})( jQuery );
```

And its called on my page this way:

```
('#start').foco({texto:'Enter the start text'}); //Works fine
```

But when I attempt to call it more than once:

```
('#start').foco({texto:'Enter the start text'}); //Doesn't work
('#end').foco({texto:'Enter the end text'});     //Does work
```

I wonder if you guys could help me to figure out how can I accomplish that.

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/mathiasbynens/jquery-placeholder it does exactly what you need.

Comment: Does the pattern hold that, in any series of calls to the plugin, it is always the last one and only the last one which is successful?  Is it possible that they all "run" but only the results of the last call persist?  (I don't have an answer, just trying to help constrain the problem.)

Comment: Have a look at jQuery watermark as well, http://code.google.com/p/jquery-watermark/

Comment: It seems to work in Chrome, http://jsfiddle.net/Ufn6t/

Comment: Thanks Matijs and Stefan. I am actually learning and experimenting as I go on JQuery, will check out those plugins tho.
Exactly David that's what happens here, I have to iterate of the textboxes to make it work everytime I need as the guys explained it already. Thank you =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `enfocar` is global. Make it local.

```
var enfocar;
```

Your plugin should probably use an `.each` like this:

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.foco = function (value) {
        return this.each(function() {
            var text = { texto: null },
                enfocar = $.extend(text, value);

            $(this).val(enfocar.texto)
                   .focus(function () {
                       if ($(this).val() == enfocar.texto) $(this).val('');
                   }).blur(function () {
                       if ($(this).val() == '') $(this).val(enfocar.texto);
                   });
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Thanks friend is working now, but Where is it iterating with the each clause?. How does each makes it work?

Comment: @CoderRoller: You don't technically need the `each` if you're only going to ever call it against one element. But in case you decide to select multiple, you'll want to include it. So `return this.each({...` iterates the elements found, and returns the jQuery object when done. This is the typical way to program a plugin. The main problem was your global variable, which was being overwritten with every new call to the plugin.

Comment: above code is giving error due to missing } and variable declaration.

Comment: @Umesh: I don't get any error. Make sure you copy/pasted correctly. I did have a misplaced `)` originally, but that was almost a half hour ago. ;) http://jsfiddle.net/wVRNH/

Comment: Added the global variable declaration: var enfocar as you suggested
and my code started to work, and yes in my code context you call a single textbox everytime but for a div containing a set of textboxes to be set on the plugin it works perfectly as you said. 

Thanks – ЖΞЖΞЖΞЖΞЖΞЖΞЖΞЖΞЖΞЖΞЖΞЖΞЖΞЖΞЖ

Answer (score 2):

I would turn it in to a "traditional multiple-element model" (not an actual keyword, but what I consider a traditional method). Basically, in your plugin you want to loop through the various elements specified in the collection (by the selector). Also, to allow chaining, we return this element so we can keep going. e.g.

```
;(function($){
  $.fn.foco = function(opts){

    var defaultOpts = {
      texto: null
    };
    opts = $.extend({}, defaultOpts, opts);

    // here's where we return the collection back. But, at the same time we
    // iterate over the collection of matched elements
    return this.each(function(i,e){

      var el = $(this);

      // insert handling code here, based on "el" is
      // the element in question

    });
  };
})(jQuery);


// implementation:
$('#a').texto({ texto: 'Search...' }); // single element
$('.required').texto({ texto: '(required)' }); // multiple elements
```

But, as @Stefan mentioned in a comment, [watermark](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-watermark/) may be a better route to go (don't re-invent the wheel). HTML5 has a new "placeholder" attribute that does exactly this while keeping it native. And, in instances where it's unsupported, it will revert back to JS code. However, without using JS, you'll have a harder time trying to style the placeholder/watermark text when it's not being directly managed by yourself.

--

My bid ([with example](http://jsfiddle.net/mSffr/)) in case you're curious:

```
(function($){
    $.fn.texto = function(watermark){
        return this.each(function(){
            var $el = $(this);

            // optional class name we can apply while they're watermarked.
            var watermarkClass = 'watermarked';

            $el.focus(function(){
                if ($el.val() == watermark){
                    $el.val('')

                    // adding the class is optional, but decorative
                    $el.removeClass(watermarkClass );
                }
            }).blur(function(){
                if ($el.val() == ''){
                    $el.val(watermark);

                    // remove the class (again, optional)
                    $el.addClass(watermarkClass );
                }
            });

            // intitial setup
            if ($el.val() == '')
            {
                $el.val(watermark);

                // once again, class is optional
                $el.addClass(watermarkClass );
            }
        });
    };
})(jQuery);

$('.texto').texto('Enter text...');
```

Comment: Thank you Brad, I am sort of new to JQuery and I am using this in my learning curve. I hope soon enough can masterize it as well as you guys do.